# Windows Image Preview on a Second Screen with a different Resolution

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

I have the following:

- Windows 8 Laptop (16:9 ratio display)
- Projector (4:3 ratio display)
- Projector Screen (4:3 ratio)
- A load of JPGs

I am trying to show the JGPs as a slide show on the projector screen thru the laptop connected to a projector. The laptop and the projector have different display resolutions.

Only by extending the displays in Windows 8 can I get a proper display from the projector. If I duplicate the displays the projector is never able to adequately fill the projector screen, by tweaking the projector I can kinda get the 16:9 display to fill the 4:3 screen, but then the image is squished and distorted.

I am trying to use Windows Preview to display a simple slide show of the JPGs but it defaults to the laptop screen - and when I use [SHIFT]-[WINDOWS KEY]-[RIGHT ARROW] to push the slide show onto the other screen, the slide show retains the resolution of the laptop screen, and instead of filling the projector screen the slide show is quite small and stuck in the top right corner of the projector screen.

I was kinda thinking what I was trying to do was simple, but after some searching online it doesn't seem so. Unless I am missing something.

Can anyone help me out?

## Is there something I can do with Windows Image Preview to make it work properly on a second monitor with a different resolution to the first?

If not, can anyone recommend some software (preferably free) which will achieve what I am trying to do.

**-- EDIT --**

I have a working solution so far - and that is to use the projector screen only, so laptop screen isnt being used and the projector is the only thing displaying. Only then can I put a slideshow on that fills the projector screen.

However I would still like to be able to use both screens, so my question still stands.

Answer (score 1):

[Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com) is a lightweight but powerful free image viewer and slideshow program.
It's long been my choice for **any** image previewing/slideshow use.

Drag the irfanview window over to the second screen before either double clicking the image to make it full screen in a simple manual slideshow; or for a more customized or automatic slideshow use the advanced slideshow function (File>>Slideshow, or press "w").